# Doesn't work the buttton css that should be adding the list

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I currently studying HTML/CSS/JS(DOM) and clon coding Instagram for practicing.  My problem is when I write some sentences and click the button, it has to be adding one the feed as an list. However, when I click the button, the button doesn't work properly. I tried to console.log something when I click the button. I guess the button didn't work. Could you check my code which part is wrong? I really appreciate your help! :)
I will share my code below.
(I Added <script ....> at the bottom of the HTML file!

This is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Westagram Main Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- header : segmantic tag -->

    <div class="wrapper"> 
        <div class="nav">
            <p class="logo"> Westagram </p>
            <input class="search-box" type="text" placeholder="&#xF002; Search", style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome">
            <div class="icons">
                <img id="compass" src="https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.wecode.co.kr/bearu/explore.png" >
                <img id="heart" src="https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.wecode.co.kr/bearu/heart.png" > 
                <img id="my-page" src=" https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.wecode.co.kr/bearu/profile.png">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main">
            <div class="feeds">
                <div class="article">
                    <div class="identi">
                        <img class="selfi" src="about.png"> 
                        <span class="name"> Jiwan Jeon </span>
                        <!-- 이름 두줄로 나오는거 해결할 -->
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>

                    <div class="pic">
                        <img src="ucscPic.png">
                    </div>

                    <div class="show-box">
                        <div class="reaction-icons">
                            <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-send-o"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>
                        </div>

                        <div class="like-counts">
                            <span>like 4,000</span>
                        <div>

                        <div class="check-comments">
                            <span>UC Santa Cruz will continue to offer most courses remotely or online for spring and summer 2021, providing in-person instruction for a small</span>
                            <a id="space" href="">expanding</a><br>
                            <a href="">Check the all comments</a>
                            <ul class="feed-comments">
                                <li>test</li>
                            </ul>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="comment">
                        <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
                        <input class="user-input" type="text" placeholder="Add Comment...">
                        <button id="post">Post</button>
                    </div>

                    
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main-right">
            <div class="top">
                <img class="selfi" src="about.png">
                <div class="main-right-name">
                    <span id="eng-name">JiwanJeon94</span><br>
                    <span id="kr-name">전지완</span>
                </div>
                
                <a href="">Transform</a>
            </div>

            <div class="middle">
                <div class="middle-words">
                    <span id="recommendation">Suggestions For You</span>
                    <a href="" id="view-all">view all</a>
                </div>
                <div class="recommendation-people">
                    <div id="recommendation-section1">
                        <img id="recommendation-people-selfi" src="about.png">
                        <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                        <a href="">Follow</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="recommendation-section1">
                        <img id="recommendation-people-selfi" src="about.png">
                        <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                        <a href="">Follow</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="recommendation-section1">
                        <img id="recommendation-people-selfi" src="about.png">
                        <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                        <a href="">Follow</a>
                    </div>  
                    <div id="recommendation-section1">
                        <img id="recommendation-people-selfi" src="about.png">
                        <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                        <a href="">Follow</a>
                    </div>                  
                    <div id="recommendation-section1">
                        <img id="recommendation-people-selfi" src="about.png">
                        <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                        <a href="">Follow</a>
                    </div>                                                  
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="footer">
                <div class="footer-top">
                    <a  href="">About</a>
                    <a  href="">Help</a>            
                    <a  href="">press</a>
                    <a  href="">API</a>     
                    <a  href="">Jobs</a>        
                    <a  href="">Privacy</a> 
                    <a  href="">Terms</a>   
                    <a  href="">Locations</a>       
                    <a  href="">TopAccounts</a> 
                    <a  href="">Hashtags</a>    
                    <a  href="">Language</a><br><br>    
            </div>              
            <span>2021 INSTAGRAM FROM FACEBOOK</span>
            <script src="main.js"></script>
            
</body>
</html>
```

This is my JS code

```
let input = document.querySelector(".user-input");
let ul = document.querySelector(".feed-comments");
let postButton = document.querySelector("#post")



function inputLength() {
    return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = ""; //after clikcing enter, clear the space
}

function addListAfterClick() {
    console.log("click is working");
    // console.log(input.value);
    if (inputLength() > 0){
        console.log("test")
        createListElement();
    }
}


function addListAfterKeypress(event){
    // console.log(event);
    if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keycode === 13){
        createListElement();
    }
}
postButton.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);
input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);
```

Comment: you can add a `debugger;` line right before `postButton.addEventListener...` and refresh the page to troubleshoot this better, then you can check in the console what's the value of `postButton` for example

Answer (score 0):

Just tested your code and it's working! When I click post button it adds item to the list and prints `click is working` and `test` in console.

My guess would be that for some reason your **main.js** file does not load. Make sure that both your HTML and main.js file are located in the same folder.

You can check if main.js is loaded by opening your browser devTools (F12) and checking Network tab.

Comment: It's weird.. I check the file location and network too but still post button not work...